# How do I use lag/lead to project opening/closing inventory over time in RedShift?

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

I have a query that would give me the opening stock for today, expected sales and purchases for the next few days (where there is no value for either, a null value is returned. What I would like to get to is to project the upcoming opening stock. How can I do this?

My current query would look very much like this in RedShift:

select date,opening_stock,sales,purchases
from inventoryandforecast

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlkaD.png)

I imagine that to accomplish the following output, I need to calculate a closing inventory for each day (where closing inventory = starting inventory - sales + purchases) and use either lag/lead for the opening inventory the next day, but I fail to understand how to do this. What should my query look like?

[Intended output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFo52.png)

Thank you for your time.